# TYPO3 Display Cond AND within OR not working

Tags: typo3, tca

I am trying to combine some conditions to display a field. I want to show the field if (CType is text AND layout is 1) OR (Ctype is textpic AND layout is 2), but it doesn't work. It enters only the second condition when CType is textpic AND layout is 2.

Here is my code:

```
'displayCond' => [
  'OR' => [
    'AND' => [
      'FIELD:layout:=:1',
      'FIELD:CType:=:text',
    ],
    'AND' => [
      'FIELD:layout:=:2',
      'FIELD:CType:=:textpic',
    ],
  ],
],
```

Can someone help out?

Comment: You're defining both items in your array with key `['displayCond']['OR']['AND']`... Thus, you're overwriting one of them. Not sure if it's possible to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, combining and nesting [display conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Columns/Properties/DisplayCond.html#displaycond) works like a charm. But the boolean operators (`AND` and `OR`) to combine several conditions have to be defined as array keys, which makes it impossible to have the same operator more than once on the same nesting level as Julian Hofmann already pointed out.

Your definition results in:

```php
'displayCond' => [
  'OR' => [
    'AND' => [
      'FIELD:layout:=:2',
      'FIELD:CType:=:textpic',
    ],
  ],
],
```

**Solution**

To solve your problem or in general, to work with more complex conditions, you can use a custom `userFunc` class as explained in the [displayCond](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Columns/Properties/DisplayCond.html#confval-displayCond) documentation. You can create custom conditions in PHP and return whether the field should be displayed (`true`) or not (`false`).

Example user function

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Your\Namespace\UserFuncs;

class DisplayCondMatcher
{
    public function checkCTypeAndLayout(array $params): bool
    {
        $CType = $params['record']['CType'];
        $layout = $params['record']['layout'];

        if (
            ($CType === 'text' && $layout === 1)
            || ($CType === 'textpic' && $layout === 2)
        ){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```php
'displayCond' => 'USER:Your\\Namespace\\UserFuncs\\DisplayCondMatcher->checkCTypeAndLayout',
```